# custom matplotlib font in ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I use matplotlib in iPython notebooks and I'm hoping to change the font-family to Gotham-Book. I have Gotham-Book installed on my machine but unfortunately, matplotlib cannot seem to find the font and keeps defaulting to a serif font. Any thoughts on how to get gotham-book working?

Here is the code I'm using.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family']=['gothambook','gotham','gotham-book','serif']

mpl.pylab.plot(range(10), mpl.pylab.sin(range(10)))
mpl.pylab.xlabel("GOTHAM BOOK FONT", size=20)
```

[image]

I can see the font is on my machine here:

```
In [12]:
matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')

Out[12]:
['/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuLGCSansMono-Oblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuLGCSansMono.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuLGCSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf',
 '/usr/local/share/fonts/gothambook/Gotham-Book.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuLGCSansMono-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf']
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe because even you *ADDED* the **font.family** to the **rcParams** but you haven't *USED* it on the **xlabel**:

```
mpl.pylab.xlabel("GOTHAM BOOK FONT", size=20)
```

Change it to this, should work:

```
mpl.pylab.xlabel("GOTHAM BOOK FONT", family='gothambook', size=20)
```

You can use **fontdict** to change the font settings on the *xlabel*, something like this works on mine:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['font.family']
Out[1]: [u'sans-serif']

plt.rcParams['font.family'].append(u'Comic Sans MS')

font = {
    'family' : 'Comic Sans MS',
    'color'  : 'blue',
    'weight' : 'normal',
    'size'   : 18,
}

plt.plot(range(10), matplotlib.pylab.sin(range(10)))
plt.xlabel('Comic Sans MS FONT', fontdict=font)
```

Results:

[image: Matplotlib using different fonts]

Alternatively you can set parameters on the fly with this:

```
plt.xlabel('Comic Sans MS FONT', family='Comic Sans MS', fontsize=18, color='blue')
```

which will have same results, you can read more about the parameters on **[Text Properties](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html#text-properties-and-layout)**

Hope this helps.